# "docker-compose: not found" in Jenkins pipeline. Tried adding path to environment

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I am running Jenkins inside Docker on my DigitalOcean droplet. When my Jenkinsfile runs "docker-compose build", I am receiving
`line 1: docker-compose: not found` while attempting to build.

My first question is that if I mounted my volume with`/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` in my docker-compose file would I still need to
add the CLI to my Dockerfile?

```
RUN curl -fsSLO https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-17.04.0-ce.tgz \
  && tar xzvf docker-17.04.0-ce.tgz \
  && mv docker/docker /usr/local/bin \
  && rm -r docker docker-17.04.0-ce.tgz
```

From looking around, it seems it should be fine with just adding the volume, but mine only worked after having both.

The second question being (similar to the first) - should docker-compose be working already by now or do I need to install docker-compose in my Dockerfile as well.

I have seen

```
pipeline {

    environment {
        PATH = "$PATH:<folder_where_docker-compose_is>"
    }
}
```

for docker-compose, is this referring to the location on my Droplet? I have tried this too but sadly that did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mounting the docker socket into your container will only make the docker client interact with the docker engine running in the host machine running the container.
You still need to install docker & docker-compose clients in order to invoke these commands from the cli.

Comment: This would mean installing dind (docker-in-docker), which I heard should be avoided. But I am assuming there is no alternative for my situation?

Comment: [This is the piece](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) I originally read a few years ago, advising against using dind in CI. If you read carefully you will see that mounting the socket does not qualify as dind, as the docker engine is still run by the host machine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install docker, docker-compose, make sure jenkins user is in group docker and set docker group id to docker group id on the host.

[Example Dockerfile](https://github.com/jmenga/docker-jenkins/blob/04d2321b8b8e9e6295eecbccfd79a01419f37cd5/Dockerfile#L28)

Comment: [Warnings against docker-in-docker](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) seem pretty common. Should I be worried about installing docker-in-docker? Or is there no other option in my case?